# Javascript - Prime Factor, Cannot format the output correctly

Tags: javascript

I have this code to find the prime divisors of a given number. I think I got the answer, but the output isn't like what I want it to be.

I want to stay within these limitations:

- Use looping (`for` or `while`) and conditionals (`if ... else`)
- Only use built-in functions `.push()` and/or `.join()` (if needed)
- Do not use ES6-specific functions.

I need the above restrictions, because I want to learn the basics first.

Here's the code:

```js
    function primeFactor(num) {
      var factor = '',
        divider = 2;
    
      while (num > 2) {
        if (num % divider == 0) {
          factor += divider;
          num = num / divider;
        }
        else {
          divider++;
        }
      }
      return factor;
    }
    
    console.log(primeFactor(90)); // 2 to the power of 1, 3 to the power of 2, 5 to the power of 1
    console.log(primeFactor(168)); // 2 to the power of 3, 3 to the power of 1, 7 to the power of 1
    console.log(primeFactor(44)); // 2 to the power of 2, 11 to the power of 1
    console.log(primeFactor(55)); // 5 to the power of 1, 11 to the power of 1
    console.log(primeFactor(26)); // 2 to the power of 1, 13 to the power of 1
    console.log(primeFactor(17)); // 17 to the power of 1
```

However, this is the output that I've got from my code:

```
2335
22237
2211
511
213
17
```

How can I turn the output to the right one?

Comment: what do you mean _prime number of a number given_?

Comment: What output ARE you expecting?

Comment: Is the intended output what you put in the code's comments? If so, please state that explicitly again in the normal text of your question.

Comment: what is **the right one**? Please explain what you want as output like you've been asked twice already!!! if it's the stuff in the comments, your code is not even a half attempt, seeing as you never have that text anywhere in your code

Comment: you can stop your loop way earlier: `while (divider*divider <= num) { ... }` and if the remaining `num > 1` then `num` is your last prime. You can skip all the numbers in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra variable to count the powers. And given the restrictions, let `factors` be an array, and only at the end turn that into a string with comma delimiters:

```js
function primeFactor(num) {
    var factors = [], // Use array to turn to string later
        divider = 2,
        power; // new variable to count the powers
    
    while (num > 2) {
        power = 0;
        while (num % divider == 0) { // loop instead of IF
            power++;
            num = num / divider;
        }
        if (power > 0) { // There is something to output
            factors.push(divider + " to the power of " + power); // Add to array
        }
        divider++;
    }
    return factors.join(", "); // Make it a string
}
    
console.log(primeFactor(90)); // 2 to the power of 1, 3 to the power of 2, 5 to the power of 1
console.log(primeFactor(168)); // 2 to the power of 3, 3 to the power of 1, 7 to the power of 1
console.log(primeFactor(44)); // 2 to the power of 2, 11 to the power of 1
console.log(primeFactor(55)); // 5 to the power of 1, 11 to the power of 1
console.log(primeFactor(26)); // 2 to the power of 1, 13 to the power of 1
console.log(primeFactor(17)); // 17 to the power of 1
```